# Why URLClassLoader.addURL protected in Java?

Tags: java, classloader

Is there any reason for `URLClassLoader.addURL` to be protected? I am asking this becuase I need to write a custom class load by extending the `URLClassLoader` and all it does is to call this protected method to add a jar file. If this wasn't pretected, then it could have been easier to add jar file dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a new URL to a classloader is typically an abstraction-violating action, and can cause inexplicable things to happen.   It is therefore hidden from normal usage.

You have an unusual use-case in which you have (I assume) concluded that the encapsulation violation is the lesser of the evils, and that it is OK to allow any part of an application to tinker with the innards of its parent classloader.  Fair enough.  And creating a custom classloader is the way to do this.  But most folks wouldn't want that to happen.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have any other option since I want to dynamically load the jar file at runtime and using OSGi is overkill for my application.

Comment: @gigadot - I don't see what your problem is.  A custom classloader that exposes the `addURL` method should only be a few lines of code ... and a no-brainer to write.

Comment: I don't have any problem with writing one. I just wanted to know if there is any security risk. Preferably, if I could avoid writing classloader, I would.

Comment: Well yes, there is a security risk of exposing `addURL` to untrusted code.  If this is a concern, your `addURL` method needs to implement the appropriate access checks.  (Don't confuse the `protected` modifier with access control / security.  They are addressing different concerns.)